# What is the world's smallest-footprint LAMP stack?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, linux-distributions

What is the world's absolute smallest known VMWare/VirtualBox image supporting basic Apache/PHP/MySQL functionality? Before or after compression.

Comment: I was hoping to find something that's small enough to email as an attachment. Like, under 20MB.

Comment: For the record, despite what the banner says, this question is **not** *not constructive*. It is definitely a worthwhile, interesting question. I myself am looking for a small, WAMP stack I can run from a flash drive. Rather, the question is *too localized* because it changes from day to day as new, smaller packages come out or new releases of existing packages come out that are bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 3):

I installed Xampp on tiny core linux on a 150mb virtual drive (virtualbox).  This gave 5mb room after installing the required python, gtk and libglade for the control panel (This took I think roughly 20mb).  After thought: not worth the disk space for the gui start/stop.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami has a killer LAMPStack VM: http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack

- based on openSUSE
- runs on VMWare or VirtualBox
- pretty light (219.4 MB zipped)

Answer (score 0):

[Xampp on Damn Small Linux](http://bvirtual.nl/2008/03/xampp-dsl-small-lamp-appliance.html)

The download weighs in at 154MB and the unpacked size is 379MB.